# Angular2 application memory leak in IOS webview

Tags: javascript, angular, memory-leaks

Is there any issue may cause memory leak with angular2 app？ My app occupy 20-30 mb memory in Safari or Chrome but 50-60mb in webview of IOS app, what can i do for this issue? 
PS: i never use subscribe of Observe object

Comment: Please share you code through  git or give plunkr link,

Comment: having the exact same problem. Did you ever find a solution?